# Error while creating a MySql table

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am trying to create a table from my command line (`Debian`), but it keeps saying I have an error in my syntax. To me it looks fine and I have got it checked by 2 different people who also cannot find the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   uuid VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
   key VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

One guy said remove NOT NULL but I still had the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KEY is a reserved word try change with my_key

```
 CREATE TABLE users (id INT( 6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      uuid VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
     my_key VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Comment: @scaisEdge - You can escape each reserved word with back-ticks `key`. So its not necessary.

Comment: @BerndBuffen but best practice of course is to NOT use reserved words at all.

Comment: @Niagaradad -  Yes you right - i also know it, but i was not the only reason why the CREATE not worked. There must be a KEY on the AUTO_INCREMENT column

Comment: @Niagaradad Thanks is exactly what i thinked about the answer.. and for this I don't understand downvote.. from someone..

Comment: @Niagaradad - Yes you right, please add a line in your answer then i can upvote it

Comment: I have update the answer adding the suggestion of @BerndBuffen

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry,**

for an AUTO_INCREMENT Field you MUST have a key on this COLUMN.

So this works:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has lots of reserved keywords that cannot be used as column names. Here you are using `key` as a column name, and since it is a reserved keyword in MySQL, you need to change the name of the column to something that is not a reserved keyword.

You can find a full list of reserved keywords that cannot be used as a column name [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Answer (score 0):

The column name "key" you used for the third column is a reserved word, all you have to do is change the name.

Well, one probably can't know all the existing keywords in a programming language but one can help himself/herself by using colour-code enabled text editor or Integrated Development Environment (IDE) when writing codes. It helps a lot.

Comment: you are basically right with not knowing all the keywords, but in MySQL (and probably many other cases) manual all the reserved words are easily listed.